# tab listener cant get grid hasselection() extjs4

Tags: extjs4.2

first of all, thanks for your support.

i have a viewport with a treepanel, gridpanel and tabpanel. when i try to know if the grid hasselection method on beforeactivate tab listener, always got a false result. but if i get treepanel hasselection method, i got the real result(true or false when select or deselect a node).

thanks in advance.

code for the grid hasselection on tab listener(wrong result):

```
listeners: {
 beforeactivate: function (tab) {
      if (Ext.getCmp('gridInfoId').getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
         console.log(tab.title);
      }
     }
 } //always got false
```

code for the treepanel hasselection on tab listener(good result):

```
listeners: {
  beforeactivate: function (tab) {
       if (Ext.getCmp('treeInfoId').getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
           console.log(tab.title);
       }
     }
  } //true or false. good!!
```

Comment: What are those listeners on? Could you post more of the code? A working jsfiddle would be helpful too.

Comment: Are you sure that you are testing the right thing ? Maybe `Ext.getCmp('gridInfoId').getSelectionModel()` really never has a selection, but the error is somewhere else in your code...